# When joining tables adapt the "on" statement depending on the query results

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

- Table_1 with columns col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D , col_E
- Table_2 with columns col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D , col_F

I would like to join them on columns col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D.

For the rows in Table_1 that do not get joined this way (as they don't have a match in Table_2), I would like to join them only on columns col_A, col_B , col_C.

If there are still rows in Table_1 that did not get joined, i would like to join them only on columns col_A, col_B.

And once that is done and there are still rows in Table_1 that did not get joined, i would like to join them only on column col_A.

I wrote the following script where i use a new table to get this result. 
Is there is a more efficient way to do this? Preferably by creating a view, not a table?

```
create table new_table (col_A nvarchar(50) , col_B nvarchar(50) , col_C nvarchar(50) 
, col_D nvarchar(50) , col_E nvarchar(50) , col_F nvarchar(50) )
go

insert into new_table
select Table_1.* , Table_2.col_F 
from Table_1 
inner join Table_2
on Table_1.col_A=Table_2.col_A 
and Table_1.col_B=Table_2.col_B 
and Table_1.col_C=Table_2.col_C 
and Table_1.col_D=Table_2.col_D
go


insert into new_table
select Table_1.* , Table_2.col_F 
from Table_1
inner join Table_2
on Table_1.col_A=Table_2.col_A 
and Table_1.col_B=Table_2.col_B 
and Table_1.col_C=Table_2.col_C
where   concat (Table_1.col_A, Table_1.col_B , Table_1.col_C , Table_1.col_D , Table_1.col_E 
        not in (select concat (col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D , col_E) from new_table)
go

insert into new_table
select Table_1.* , Table_2.col_F 
from Table_1
inner join Table_2
on Table_1.col_A=Table_2.col_A 
and Table_1.col_B=Table_2.col_B
where   concat (Table_1.col_A, Table_1.col_B , Table_1.col_C , Table_1.col_D , Table_1.col_E 
        not in (select concat (col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D , col_E) from new_table)
go

insert into new_table
select Table_1.* , Table_2.col_F 
from Table_1
inner join Table_2
on Table_1.col_A=Table_2.col_A
where   concat (Table_1.col_A, Table_1.col_B , Table_1.col_C , Table_1.col_D , Table_1.col_E 
        not in (select concat (col_A, col_B , col_C , col_D , col_E) from new_table)
go
```

Comment: INNER JOIN ON is CROSS JOIN WHERE, ie rows that are made from pairs of input rows & that satisfy the ON condition. What rows do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join them on just colA and then assign some different numbers:

```
WITH cte AS(

  SELECT
    CASE WHEN t1.D = t2.D THEN 100 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN t1.C = t2.C THEN 10 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN t1.B = t2.B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as whatMatched,
    *
  FROM
    t1 JOIN t2 on t1.A = t2.A
)
```

Now if a row got 111 we know that all (ABCD) matched, got 0 then only A matched etc..

So we can ask for only some rows:

```
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE whatmatched IN (111,11,1,0)
```

And lastly if there were multiples (matching on just A might mean there are duplicates), we can assign a row number to them in descending order and only take the first row:

```
SELECT x.* FROM
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY whatmatched DESC) rown FROM cte WHERE whatmatched IN (111,11,1,0)) x
WHERE x.rown = 1
```

#### If it suits you better to use letters

we can assess the matches, choose only A, AB, ABC, or ABCD, then pick the most specific one by looking at the `LEN`gth of the match string:

```
WITH cte AS(

  SELECT
    'A' +
    CASE WHEN t1.B = t2.B THEN 'B' ELSE '' END + 
    CASE WHEN t1.C = t2.C THEN 'C' ELSE '' END + 
    CASE WHEN t1.D = t2.D THEN 'D' ELSE '' END as whatMatched,
    *
  FROM
    t1 JOIN t2 on t1.A = t2.A
)
SELECT x.* FROM
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(whatmatched) DESC) rown FROM cte WHERE whatmatched IN ('A','AB','ABC','ABCD')) x
WHERE x.rown = 1
```

If you want ties (i.e. a row from `t1` that matches two rows from `t2` because their A/B/C is the same and D differs, use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` so they end up tied for first place

Comment: This is genius!